# Set private npm registry on docker node.js application from WebStorm run/debug configuration

Tags: node.js, docker, intellij-idea, dockerfile, webstorm

How to change ***npm registry*** for ***Node.JS interpreter using docker image*** in *`run/debug configuration`*?

I realised that WebStorm automatically regenerate `JetBrains.Dockerfile`, but when I tried to edit that file directly and hit play button again, WebStorm will regenerate new dockerfile instead of using the updated file.

Is there anyway to use private npm registry in this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I found the work around to achieve this:

First I added new npm script in package.json:

```
"set:registry": "npm config set registry=\"npm repository\"",
```

Then in the run/debug configuration, I added `Before launch: npm script` to run `set:registry` script task so it will set the registry to the private npm registry before run npm install.

NB: Still looking for the best way to accomplish this, since this workaround has some changes in the package.json file.

Comment: what about adding `RUN npm -g config set registry YOUR_REGISTRY` into your DockerFIle?